# Cross product of two vectors in Python

Tags: python

How can I calculate the cross product of two vectors without the use of programming libraries?

E.g given vectors `a = (1, 2, 3)` and `b = (4, 5, 6)`

Comment: The formula for the cross product can be found at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html. Come back after you've read that if you still have a programming problem.

Answer (score 61):

are you asking about the formula for the cross product? Or how to do indexing and lists in python?

The basic idea is that you access the elements of a and b as a[0], a[1], a[2], etc. (for x, y, z) and that you create a new list with [element_0, element_1, ...]. We can also wrap it in a function.

On the vector side, the cross product is the antisymmetric product of the elements, which also has a nice geometrical interpretation.

Anyway, it would be better to give you hints and let you figure it out, but that's not really the SO way, so...

```
def cross(a, b):
    c = [a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1],
         a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2],
         a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]]

    return c
```

Comment: You're welcome (but there's no need to thank each of us individually). However, you could "accept" one of the answers -- hint, hint,...

Answer (score 42):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,0])  
b = np.array([0,1,0])  
#print the result    
print(np.cross(a,b))
```

Comment: While not an answer to the requirements, Paul has a point:

If you need that kind of things, you really *should* look into numpy!

Also, if you are playing with 3D vectors in your studies, check out VPython - it makes visualizing these things immensely easy and fun.

Comment: Anonymous editor tried to add this, which I thought should be a comment: so the answer you get is [0 0 1] that user can collect as (0i+0j+0k) as cross product of the given 2 vector

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement the cross product yourself you may see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_cross_product
or a math/physics book.
Shortly (a1, a2, a3) X (b1, b2, b3) = (a2*b3-a3*b2, a3*b1-a1*b3, a1*b2-a2*b1)

Answer (score 1):

for multiple dimensions, this might work;

```
    def crossProd(a,b):
      dimension = len(a)
      c = []
      for i in range(dimension):
        c.append(0)
        for j in range(dimension):
          if j <> i:
            for k in range(dimension):
              if k <> i:
                if k > j:
                  c[i] += a[j]*b[k]
                elif k < j:
                  c[i] -= a[j]*b[k]
      return c
```

Comment: How about using recursion for this?...  It would be more elegant.

Comment: You may want to use != instead of <>

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
def cross_product(u,v):  
    dim = len(u)
    s = []
    for i in range(dim):
        if i == 0:
            j,k = 1,2
            s.append(u[j]*v[k] - u[k]*v[j])
        elif i == 1:
            j,k = 2,0
            s.append(u[j]*v[k] - u[k]*v[j])
        else:
            j,k = 0,1
            s.append(u[j]*v[k] - u[k]*v[j])
    return s
```

Comment: In the spirit of teaching: this is a pretty bad way to do it -- the loop doesn't really do anything, since there is a check, in order, for each of the three different indices, each of which appends to the existing result in that order! Could just do, e.g., `s.append(u[1]*v[2] - u[2]*v[1]); s.append(u[2]*v[0] - u[0]*v[2]); s.append(u[0]*v[1] - u[1]*v[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a successror funtion z,This is to help write the formulas of the cross product In a slightly consise way.here is the code

```
    from numpy import zeros
    def z(a):
      if a == 0 or a == 1:
       return a+1
      elif a == 2:
       return 0
    n = 3
    i = 0
    v = zeros(n, float)
    v1 = zeros(n, float)
    v2 = zeros(n, float)
    v1[0] = float(input("enter x component of v1 "))
    v1[1] = float(input("enter y component of v1 "))
    v1[2] = float(input("enter z component of v1 "))
    v2[0] = float(input("enter x component of v2 "))
    v2[1] = float(input("enter y component of v2 "))
    v2[2] = float(input("enter z component of v2 "))


    def cp(x, y):
     global i
     while i < n:
      v[i] = x[z(i)]*y[z(z(i))]-x[z(z(i))]*y[z(i)]
      i = i + 1
     return v


    ans = cp(v1, v2)
    print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to contribute to SO. It may be helpful but you're not answering the question as well it doesn't meet the requirement of avoiding use of libraries, like numpy. Please read questions more carefully next time.