# Plane equation for 3D vectors

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

I want to find a 3D plane equation given 3 points. I have got the normal calculated after applying the cross product. But the equation of a plane is known to be the normal multiply by another vector which what I am taught to be as P.OP. I substitute my main reference point as OP and i want P to be in (x, y, z) form. So that I can get something like e.g,

```
OP = (1, 2, 3)
```

I want to get something like that:

```
(x-1)
(y-2)
(z-3)
```

May I know how?
Below is my reference code.(Note: plane_point_1_x(), plane_point_1_y(), plane_point_1_z() are all functions asking for the user input of the respective points)

```
"""
I used Point P as my reference point so I will make use of it in this section
"""

vector_pop_x = int('x') - int(plane_point_1_x())
vector_pop_y = int('y') - int(plane_point_1_y())
vector_pop_z = int('z') - int(plane_point_1_z())

print vector_pop_x, vector_pop_y, vector_pop_z
```

All the above is what i did, but for some reason it did not work. I think the problem lies in the x, y , z part.

Comment: Don't you think this isn't exactly programming related? Btw, `int("x")` doesn't work, what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @gs -- confused why this would be inappropriate. Asking about algorithms and how to implement them has a long tradition here.

Answer (score 5):

Say you have three known points, each with (x, y, z). For example:

```
p1 = (1, 2, 3)
p2 = (4, 6, 9)
p3 = (12, 11, 9)
```

Make them into symbols that are easier to look at for further processing:

```
x1, y1, z1 = p1
x2, y2, z2 = p2
x3, y3, z3 = p3
```

Determine two vectors from the points:

```
v1 = [x3 - x1, y3 - y1, z3 - z1]
v2 = [x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1]
```

Determine the [cross product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984823/327026) of the two vectors:

```
cp = [v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1],
      v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2],
      v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]]
```

A plane can be described using a simple equation *ax* + *by* + *cz* = *d*. The three coefficients from the cross product are *a*, *b* and *c*, and *d* can be solved by substituting a known point, for example the first:

```
a, b, c = cp
d = a * x1 + b * y1 + c * z1
```

Now do something useful, like determine the *z* value at *x*=4, *y*=5. Re-arrange the simple equation, and solve for *z*:

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = (d - a * x - b * y) / float(c)  # z = 6.176470588235294
```

Answer (score 5):

If I am not mistaken, one good solution here contains mistypes

```
vector1 = [x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1]
vector2 = [x3 - x1, y3 - y1, z3 - z1]

cross_product = [vector1[1] * vector2[2] - vector1[2] * vector2[1], -1 * (vector1[0] * vector2[2] - vector1[2] * vector2[0]), vector1[0] * vector2[1] - vector1[1] * vector2[0]]

a = cross_product[0]
b = cross_product[1]
c = cross_product[2]
d = - (cross_product[0] * x1 + cross_product[1] * y1 + cross_product[2] * z1)
```

Tried previous (author's) version, but had to check it. With couple more minuses in formulas seems correct now.

Answer (score 4):

One good way is:

```
| x1 y1 z2 1 |
| x2 y2 z2 1 |
| x3 y3 z3 1 | = 0
| x  y  z  1 |
```

Where the vertical pipes mean the determinant of the matrix, and `(x1 y1 z1)`, `(x2 y2 z2)`, and `(x3 y3 z3)` are your given points.

Comment: how do i define a variable to it? And may i know how does it work in python? Sorry for the newbie question because i do not really understand it and it does not seem to be working, maybe i did it wrongly or something

Comment: The plane is the set of all points `(x y z)` that satisfy this equation. So, if you have your three reference points, plug them in, and you can test any other point for being on the plane with the above equation. Or, if you have, say, the point's `x` and `y` coordinates, you can solve for the other.

Answer (score 3):

Plane implicit Eqn:

All points **P** = (x, y, z) satisfying

<**n**, **QP**> = 0

where

- **n** is the plane normal vector,
- **Q** is some point on the plane (any will do)
- **QP** is the vector from **Q** to **P**
- <**a**, **b**> is the scalar (dot) product operator.

(Remember that **QP** can be computed as **P** - **Q**)

Answer (score 2):

I wish this answer already existed.  Coded from http://www.had2know.com/academics/equation-plane-through-3-points.html

Supposing 3 points p1, p2, p3 - consisting of [x1, y1, z1], etc.

```
vector1 = [x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1]
vector2 = [x3 - x1, y3 - y1, z3 - z1]
cross_product = [vector1[1] * vector2[2] - vector1[2] * vector2[1], -1 * vector1[0] * v2[2] - vector1[2] * vector2[0], vector1[0] * vector2[1] - vector1[1] * vector2[0]]
d = cross_product[0] * x1 - cross_product[1] * y1 + cross_product[2] * z1

a = cross_product[0]
b = cross_product[1]
c = cross_product[2]
d = d
```

Comment: Beware: this answer contains arithmetic errors. See MasterAler's answer for the correct version of this.